# Android app gets stuck when I turn tablet - first timer

Tags: android

I'm first time developer for these types of devices, and UI in general, so I could be missing something basic and obvious.

Everything seems to work fine in the emulator, but I don't know how to simulate turning it.
So I tried running the app on my pandigital (white model - lowest of the low it seems), and each time I turn the Android, it freezes up.  At least the UI freezes up, I believe the debug messages are still printing.
This is a home project, I don't have other devices to try it on.

Sorry for being so vague, it's an issue I have been a bit neglecting, trying to work on more interesting issues first, but it's an issue that is bothering me in the back of my mind.

Anyway, I have an Activity that starts up a thread, and creates a class which responds to various events, it implements: MainInterface and SurfaceHolder.Callback.  Is there something else I should be handling? possibly?
Is there some specific call I get when the tablet is turned?  I'd like to put a debug message in there.

Comment: One thing I think you are not realizing. When you rotate the screen the running activity is killed. And remade in the new orientation. That will cause whatever thread you ran to run again.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you state in your AndroidManifest.xml that this activity will handle rotation events itself (perhaps because you copied it from some project where the activity did do this), and that this statement is a lie, your activity actually makes no attempt to handle rotation.

If this is the case, a sound way to solve your problem is simply to remove the lying [android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) from your manifest.